# jquery facebook wall .live

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebox

I am using the jquery plugin here [**Facebook Wall jquery plugin**](http://neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall) and I want to show the post wall in jquery Facebox. For some reason `fb.wall` works fine if its not loaded from within Facebox.

Does anyone know how to set `fb.wall` to `.live` or how to get the wall posts working inside Facebox?

I have had a look around for a solution but was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a cross domain issue. Try a plugin like [jQuery Socialist](http://plugins.in1.com) instead. It handles cross-domain requests and works to create a Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.. social wall.